# relay email quota

Tags: postfix, email-server, quota

I have a mail server which relays mail to the network.
i have implemented a disk quota on each user which is:-
1 user can send mails upto a limit of 200 Mb,but this is creating a problem as some users are sending less mails and some of the users are sending more mails.
So Now i want a user qouta to limit the number of emails sent by a single user to say=10000 emails per year.

> I have postfix as an MTA and centOs 5 as my mail server configuration.
>   can anybody help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question, but you might consider [policyd](http://www.policyd.org/). It does support postfix.

Comment: ok i will see this and update you.